# select data from multiple tables with total and other advance sql

Tags: sql

i am having below table structure in my database

```
table1
userid, userName, userAddress
1,Manish,india
2,rita,usa
3,mariya,vietnam

table2
userid(fk table1),transactionType,transactionDesc,transactionAmt
1,                  credit,        10 installations,    50
2,                  credit,         8 installations,    40
1,                  debit,          1 Cust. Complain,    5
1,                  debit,          2 uninformed leave, 10
3,                  credit,         2 installations,    10
```

scenario
i wanted to build an sql query for selection of below structured data

```
userName,balanceToPay
manish,       35
rita,         40
mariya,       10
```

what i was doing was

```
datatable users = select * from table1

then foreach id in users
{  int total_credit = 0,total_debit=0
   datatable credits = select transactionAmt from table2 where transactionType='credit' and userid = id
   foreach TransAmt in credits
      total_credit += transAmt

   datatable debits = select transactionAmt from table2 where tansactionType = 'debit' and userid=id
   foreach TransAmt in debits
      total_debit += transAmt

   publish row userName, balanceToPay(total_credits - total_debits)
}
```

it was working well when data was small like upto 30-40 users
but now its required for 3000-4000 users

if same applied in 3000 users then system will be waiting for longer n longer.

so i need experts to help me out in building an sql query

i tried SUM() but then it will only reduce inner loop.
so i thought of taking help of stack experts

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: You've tagged several RDBMS here (`sql-server` and `t-sql`, `mysql` and `sqllite`) Which is correct? This doesn't look like T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be executing a single aggregation query:

```
select t2.userid,
       sum(case when t2.transactionType = 'credit' then transactionAmt
                when t2.transactionType = 'debit' then -transactionAmt
                else 0
           end) as balanceToPay
from table2 t2
group by t2.userid;
```

I'll leave it to you adding the `join` to bring in the name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query

```
 SELECT  userName ,
    ( credit - debit ) AS balanceToPay
FROM    ( SELECT    A.userName ,
                SUM(CASE WHEN B.transactionType = 'credit'
                         THEN B.transactionAmt
                         ELSE 0
                    END) AS Credit ,
                SUM(CASE WHEN B.transactionType = 'debit'
                         THEN B.transactionAmt
                         ELSE 0
                    END) AS debit
      FROM      table1 A
                INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.userid = B.userid
                GROUP BY A.userName
    ) L
```